# Accuracy for every epoch is starting with 0 instead of 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

[image]

How to plot graph in Keras stating from 1 instead of 0. I have trained a model for 20 epochs and the graph is showing epoch x-axis from 0 to 19.

Code :

```
  hist = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator,  epochs=20, 
  batch_size=batchsize)

  plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
  plt.subplot(2,1,1)

  plt.plot(hist.history['accuracy'],marker='o')
  plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'],marker='p')
  plt.axis(ymin=0.0,ymax=1)
  plt.grid()
  plt.title('VGG16 Model Accuracy')
  plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
  plt.xlabel('Epochs')
  plt.legend(['Training Accuracy', 'Validation Accuracy'])
  plt.show()
```

How this problem could be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the graph using only the train accuracies. But you can obtain the same adding also your validation accuracies:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# acc_history is the same as your hist.history['accuracy']
acc_history = [0.9002329707145691, 0.9219149351119995, 0.9280775785446167, 0.9322110414505005, 0.9352172017097473, 0.937546968460083, 0.9384863972663879, 0.9416428804397583, 0.9418307542800903, 0.9441981315612793, 0.9461145401000977, 0.9464902877807617, 0.9477679133415222, 0.9504734873771667, 0.9524274468421936, 0.954456627368927, 0.9550578594207764, 0.9591537714004517, 0.9588531255722046, 0.9635878801345825, 0.9638884663581848, 0.9652412533760071, 0.9674583077430725, 0.9688861966133118, 0.9716669321060181]

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)

plt.plot(acc_history, marker='o')
# change the values on the ticks, starting from 1
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(acc_history)), np.arange(1, len(acc_history)+1))

plt.axis(ymin=0.0, ymax=1)
plt.grid()
plt.title('VGG16 Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['Training Accuracy'])
plt.show()
```

Basically `xticks` lets you specify the labels that you want on your x axis.

The output graph is:

[image]

Comment: x-axis numbering is starting with 1 but ending at 8 but the graph is till 20 epochs

Comment: Can you please do `print(hist.history['accuracy'])` and add the outcome to your question?

Comment: print(hist.history['accuracy'])
[0.9002329707145691, 0.9219149351119995, 0.9280775785446167, 0.9322110414505005, 0.9352172017097473, 0.937546968460083, 0.9384863972663879, 0.9416428804397583, 0.9418307542800903, 0.9441981315612793, 0.9461145401000977, 0.9464902877807617, 0.9477679133415222, 0.9504734873771667, 0.9524274468421936, 0.954456627368927, 0.9550578594207764, 0.9591537714004517, 0.9588531255722046, 0.9635878801345825, 0.9638884663581848, 0.9652412533760071, 0.9674583077430725, 0.9688861966133118, 0.9716669321060181]

Comment: I've updated the answer using your values. Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot, could this be done by passing the accuracy metrics instead of values, as it is part of the code and graphs are to be generated after the fit function? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use `hist.history['accuracy']` directly, as you are doing in your code.